# Issue with Maven + Spring Boot + JPA + Hibernate project?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, maven, jpa

I have a parent POM project that declares spring version as 3.2 and hiberate entity manager version as 4.1.1 (lets call parent, P). I have another project which is child to this parent and inherits the mentioned dependency Management (lets call child C1). I am building a new project which I expect to the child of the mentioned parent and also is dependent on child C1, (lets call this new child C2).

- Parent P1 (Parent Pom project, declares spring 3.2 and hibernate 4.1.1)
  Child C1 (Java project, uses dependency management for Parent P1) 
  Child C2 (new J2EE project, dependent on Child C1, Declares P1 as parent but       has its own dependency management. Uses spring-boot-dependencies(1.3.2), hibernate-entitymanager(4.3.11), spring-framework-bom(4.2.4), dependent on spring-boot-starter-data-jpa and spring-boot-starter-data-rest.

To make this work, I have been trying to solve various dependency issues. But have got stuck on one. Please see below. Please suggest how should I manage these dependencies? How should i manage the dependency of spring-data-commons?

> Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError:
>   org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getTargetRepository(Lorg/springframework/data/repository/core/RepositoryInformation;)Ljava/lang/Object;
>          at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:185)
>   ~[spring-data-commons-1.11.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
>          at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.initAndReturn(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:251)
>   ~[spring-data-commons-1.11.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
>          at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:237)
>   ~[spring-data-commons-1.11.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
>          at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.java:84)
>   ~[spring-data-jpa-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
>          at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1637)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
>          at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
>          ... 50 common frames omitted

Comment: Version Conflict. Check your Spring Data JPA and Spring Data Core Versions

Comment: Spring Boot doesn't work with spring 3.2 and the stack trace indicates a version mismatch between jars.

Answer (score 0):

Exclude Spring 3.2 transitive dependencies from the child C1 :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId></groupId>
    <artifactId>C1</artifactId>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactIdId>spring-XXXX</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Already done that. infact i am excluding all transitive dependencies from child C1,  pom of child C2 : - <dependency>
    <groupId></groupId>
    <artifactId>C1</artifactId>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>*</groupId>
            <artifactIdId>*</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>

Comment: Then try to update your `spring-data-jpa` version. In your stacktrace, i see you're using `spring-data-commons` in `1.11.2.RELEASE` version and `spring-data-jpa`in `1.3.2.RELEASE` version, that's quite an old version.